# Are there any images from ancient times in which Heracles is shown with a cornucopia?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, greek-mythology

I have read in Wikipedia the cornucopia was created when Heracles wrestled with the river god Achelous and wrenched off one of his horns.

Are there any images from ancient times in which Heracles is shown  with a cornucopia (Not necessarily with presence of Achelous)?

Comment: That seems kind of tenuous as a link to being a "god of fertility". Anyway, are you requesting ancient imagery of Hercules with a cornucopia, or are you asking whether he was definitively a god of fertility? Title and last sentence aren't really the same.

Comment: Yes, they are separate questions. I have asked the second because it is important to me as the first.

Comment: This might be better served by asking in the [mythology.se] site, if you have access to it.

Comment: In fact you could ask for images here and ask whether he was a god of fertility there.

Comment: For sure. Does exist a way to transfer the question to there?

Comment: Would be easier to manually create a new question I think. You may have to go through [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58307/mythology) to get to Myth.SE.

Comment: Can't commit while already in private beta, might have to wait a few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Description

English: Herma representing Herakles with a cornucopia. Pentelic marble, Roman artwork from the 2nd century BC after a Greek original of the 5th century. The worn surface of the statue is the result from long exposure to the elements.

http://books.google.com/books?id=ff51JeXhHXUC&pg=PA423&lpg=PA423&dq=heracles+cornucopia+vase&source=bl&ots=2pfsoShwPL&sig=VfxoQin8w3SJSW5omjBTfPsxYaw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HQ5RVaL8Ncr1oATrooCYDg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=heracles%20cornucopia%20vase&f=false

Heracles and an old man with a cornucopia. (380-360 BC)